# I'm a seven letter word. What am I?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction

> I'm a **seven** letter word.
>
> My first three letter stands for **animal** name.
>
> My 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th letter stands for **food**.
>
> My 4th, 5th, and 6th stands for **utensil**.
>
> My 5th, 6th, and 7th remains **same every year**.

**What am I?**

**Hint :**

> Word start from 'A'

Comment: Do you have a solution or you heard it from somewhere?

Comment: I have a solution.

Comment: A very nice puzzle indeed.

Comment: We have people in many time zones, so it's considered good form to wait 24 hours before adding extra hints.

Comment: You are "A seven letter word"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Art thou

> Apetaly?

My first three letter stands for animal name.

> Ape

My 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th letter stands for food.

> Peta, like pita bread.

My 4th, 5th, and 6th stands for utensil.

> Tal, As in a TAL Vogue Double-Wall Vacuum Insulated Stainless Steel Water Bottle

My 5th, 6th, and 7th remains same every year.

> Aly, as in ally, do tend to remain the same every year.

Hint:

> Word start from 'A', apetaly starts with the letter 'A'

Comment: *Art thou?* Nice. Good answer, too! $(+1)$

Comment: This was the answer? I'm sorry, but this is absurd. The solution relies on a misspelling of the word 'pita', a completely unknown product line for a Walmart water bottle which isn't even a kitchen utensil, a misspelling of the word 'ally', which certainly don't remain the same EVERY year.  Far better was the suggestion of "average."

Comment: @Parseltongue, I'm confused too, for those very same reasons. The water bottle one especially I thought was flimsy at **best**

Answer (score 8):

how about

> average?

clue 1:

> birds are of class aves

clue 2:

> 'vera' as in aloe vera

clue 3:

> rag is an article for household use

clue 4:

> the one clue that doesn't fit very well. Maybe the fact that you 'age' and grow older doesn't ever change?

Answer (score 4):

That must not be the correct answer, but since nobody has found yet, I'll show my best try:

My suggestion is

> BOATSER

Because

1.

> Boa is certainly an [animal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boa_%28genus%29) name

2.

> [Oats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oat) is food

3. 

> TSE is a text editing [tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_SemWare_Editor), if not a [spoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spoony_Experiment).

4.

> Ser is the same every year. Err, isn't it ?

Answer (score 3):

Could you be

> Arabica ?

My first three letter stands for animal name.

> Ara -> [Arachnida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_classes)

My 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th letter stands for food.

> rabi is a crop.

My 4th, 5th, and 6th stands for utensil.

> bic. BIC pens

My 5th, 6th, and 7th remains same every year.

> TBD

Comment: For your first hint, not note that you three first letters are directly the name of a rot13(cneebg).

Answer (score 1):

> The possible solutions are : ['abasers', 'abashes', 'amidins', 'amusers', 'aneared', 'average', 'awakens']

None of which clearly solve the riddle.

Comment: How did you narrow it down?

Comment: I used a gigantic word list and pruned it one step at a time --> restrict length to 7 letters, must start with A, the first three letters must be in the larger word list --> and so on.

Comment: I'm guessing at least one of the interior words isn't a proper word. It might be a brand name or something similar.

Comment: Well, the word 'average' can be found in [this answer above](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70163/im-a-seven-letter-word-what-am-i/70190#70190), and it is a good one, perhaps having solved the riddle. Also, I strongly recommend you hide your answer in spoiler quotes/tags `>!` in order to not spoil the answer for other users attempting to solve the puzzle. $(+1)$ nonetheless :)